# Find pdf of given random variable

Tags: random-variables, density-function

I have the following question. I would like to get some feedback regarding my approach.

> Let $U$ be random variable such that $U\sim \text{Unif}\left((0,1)\right)$. Define the following r.v:
>   $$Z_1=\begin{cases}\ln(2U),& 0<U\le \frac{1}{2}\\ -\ln(2(1-U)),& \frac{1}{2}<U<1\end{cases} \quad , \quad Z_2=\sqrt{-2\ln(1-U)}$$ Derive the PDFs of $Z_1,Z_2$.

**My try:**

First compute the CDFs of $Z_1,Z_2$ and then derive the results in order to get the PDFs.

---

For $Z_1$ we split into cases:

1. For $0<U\le \dfrac{1}{2}$ (of course $Z_1\le 0$): $$F_{Z_1}(z)=P\left(Z_1\le z\right)=P\left(\ln(2U)\le z\right)=P\left(2U\le \exp(z)\right)=P\left(U\le \frac{1}{2}\exp(z)\right)$$
2. For $\dfrac{1}{2}<U<1$ (of course $Z_1>0$): \begin{align*}F_{Z_1}(z)&=P(Z_1\le z)=P\left(-\ln(2(1-U))\le z\right)\\&=P\left(\frac{1}{2(1-U)}\le\exp(z)\right)=P\left(U\le 1-\frac{1}{2}\exp(z)\right)\end{align*}

Thus, $F_{Z_1}(z_1)=\begin{cases} \dfrac{1}{2}\exp(z),&z\le 0 \\ 1-\dfrac{1}{2}\exp(-z),&z>0\end{cases}\implies \boxed{f_{Z_1}(z_1)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{1}{2}\exp(z),&z\le 0 \\ \dfrac{1}{2}\exp(-z),&z>0\end{cases}}$

---

For $Z_2$ we first notice that $Z_2>0$, i.e $\forall z_2\le 0: f_{Z_2}(z_2)=0$. Now, \begin{align}F_{Z_2}(z)&=P(Z_2\le z)=P\left(\sqrt{-2\ln(1-U)}\le z\right)=P\left(-2\ln(1-U)\le z^2\right) \\ &=P\left(-\ln(1-U)\le \frac{z^2}{2}\right)=P\left(\frac{1}{1-U}\le\exp\left(\frac{z^2}{2}\right)\right)=P\left(U\le 1-\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{2}\right)\right)\end{align}Thus $F_{Z_2}(z_2)=\begin{cases}0,&z_2\le 0 \\ 1-\exp\left(-\dfrac{z_2^2}{2}\right),&z_2>0\end{cases}\implies\boxed{f_{Z_2}(z_2)=\begin{cases}0,&z_2\le 0\\ z_2\exp\left(-\dfrac{z_2^2}{2}\right),&z_2>0\end{cases}}$

---

Thank you.

Comment: Can someone please comment?

Comment: Why downvoting?

Comment: I think you have to specify what exactly you are asking others  to do.

Comment: @AkshayHegde, I only look for some feedback regarding my work. If it is correct, it is enough to tell it's correct... If there are mistakes, please point them to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your results are correct, it would have been better if you had included the restriction on $U$ directly in your probability formula.

For example , in your first line , taking $z=1, $$ P\left(U\le \frac{1}{2}\exp(z)\right)=1$ , while in your context it is actually $0.5$ because of your restriction on $U$.

On my side, let $z \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$P(Z_1 \leq z)=P(Z_1 \leq z, U \in]0,\frac{1}{2}])+P(Z_1 \leq z, U \in]\frac{1}{2},1[)$$
$$=P(log(2U) \leq z, U \in]0,\frac{1}{2}])+P(-log(2(1-U)) \leq z, U \in]\frac{1}{2},1[)$$
$$=P(U \leq \frac{e^z}{2}, U \in]0,\frac{1}{2}])+P(U \leq 1-\frac{e^{-z}}{2}, U \in]\frac{1}{2},1[)$$
We have that $\frac{e^z}{2} >0$, therefore

$$P(U \leq \frac{e^z}{2}, U \in]0,\frac{1}{2}])=P(U \leq min(\frac{1}{2},\frac{e^z}{2}))=min(\frac{1}{2},\frac{e^z}{2})$$

$1>1-\frac{e^{-z}}{2}>\frac{1}{2}$ when $z>0$, and $1-\frac{e^{-z}}{2}<\frac{1}{2}$ when $z<0$, therefore

$$P(U \leq 1-\frac{e^{-z}}{2}, U \in]\frac{1}{2},1[)=P(\frac{1}{2}<U \leq 1-\frac{e^{-z}}{2})1_{\{z>0\}}=\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-z})1_{\{z>0\}}$$

Thus,

$$F_{Z_1}(z)=min(\frac{1}{2},\frac{e^z}{2})+\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-z})1_{\{z>0\}}$$

which is what you have.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks!